# sqlite with winapi threads in c++

Tags: multithreading, winapi

hi am trying to use sqlite inside winapi thread but sqlite prepare statment is not working i do not why please help look it my code the sqlite3_prepare_v2  is not returning SQLITE_OK

```
DWORD WINAPI dloader(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    sqlite3 *db;     // databse handler 
    sqlite3_stmt *stat;    // statment ....  
    char *q;
    q="INSERT INTO search (id,fname,fpath) VALUES (NULL,?,?)";
    LPSTR f = (LPSTR)lpParameter, ff;
    size_t s = lstrlen(f); DWORD bw;
cout<<"\nin loader";
    if ((s > 0) && (lstrcmp(&f[s-4], ".jpg") == 0))
    {
        ff = PathFindFileNameA(f);
        s = lstrlen(f);
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, q, strlen(q), &stat, 0) == SQLITE_OK){
        // Bind values 
        cout<<"\nvalues binded";
        sqlite3_bind_text(stat, 1, ff, strlen(ff), 0); // file name
        sqlite3_bind_text(stat, 2, f, strlen(f), 0);   // file path + file name
        sqlite3_step(stat);   // prepare statemnt Ready
        sqlite3_finalize(stat);    
   }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't print or log error messages when you detect an error, it's your own fault you don't know what's happening.

Comment: i cant convert sqlite3 integer error codes

Comment: Have a look at the sqlite API. There _is_ a function to convert error codes to error strings.

Comment: error code is 1  , k let me translate it

Comment: 1   /* SQL error or missing database */      but database already exists created in parent process

Comment: thanks for your help :) done actually problem was that i forget to open database inside thread , to insert in every thread you have to open it first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSET` is not a command. That should be `INSERT`. You need to familiarize yourself with error handling. Don't run commands without checking the return codes and logging the error messages. You wouldn't have to ask this question if you followed [this documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Comment: Ya with insert it not work too